# Prove that solution to Cauchy problem is odd

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm required to show that the maximal solution $y(x)$ in the open interval $I$ to the Cauchy problem

$$\left\{ 
\begin{gathered}
  y' = \frac{1}{{1 + xy}}, \\
  y(0) = 0, \\ 
\end{gathered}
 \right.$$

is an odd function. That is the same as having $z(x)=-y(-x)=y(x)$ (for all $\,x \in I)$.

Clearly, $z(0)=0$, so my attempt would be to show that $z'(x)=y'(x)$. Therefore, $z(x)$ would also be a solution to the Cauchy problem. With the Picard–Lindelöf theorem, $z=y$, due to the uniqueness of the solution in $U=\mathbb{R}^2-\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: xy=-1\}$, so $y(x)$ would be odd.

Unfortunately, I've computed $$z'(x)=\dfrac{1}{1-xy}\neq\dfrac{1}{1+xy},$$ so I can't see how $y(x)$ is odd, even though my reference says so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful with the signs (and the equation). If we want to use Picard-Lindelöf, we have to show that $z$ fulfills the **same equation** as $y$ does (which implies $z'= y'$ [if we had this, we do not need Picard-Lindelöf], the fundamental theorem of calculus would be sufficient]). So letting $z(x) = -y(-x)$, we have - as you write
$$ z'(x) = y'(-x) = \frac 1{1 - x\cdot y(-x)} $$
But this isn't an equation for $z$. You have to replace $y(-x)$ by a term in $z$ again. Can you conclude?

Answer (score 0):

teh derivative of an ODD function is an EVEN function

$ y(-x)=-y(x) $ so $ y'(-x)=y'(x) $

make the change of variable $ x=-u $ so $ \frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{dy}{du} $

apply this changes and you will see that your ODE is invariant under the change $ x=-u $ so it must be an odd function the solution